# Invalid resource selected while importing WSDL created in Jdeveloper

Tags: osb

I have created a DBadapter service in Jdeveloper and now I want to create a business service in eclipse and integrate this buisness service with the DBAdapter.

So, I have imported .wsdl,.jca and .xml files from DBAdapter and placed them in respective folders in Oracle service bus project. Now, in my business service, i have selected Service type as WSDL Web Service, and I have given the path of WSDL present in my OSB project.

But , here I am getting an error as "Invalid Resource Selected". I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

Appreciate all suggestions

Regards
Anurag

Comment: Check the document(OSB-JCA DB.doc) at the following location and let me know if you have followed this or not:https://bitbucket.org/pmathur/osb-documents

Answer (score 0):

When you want to publish a JCA DatabaseAdapter as a business service in OSB console you have to click in the button like (a box with arrow) in the JCA file.

Or if you want to do it in Eclipse you have to follow this guide
(the correct step is http://guidoschmutz.files.wordpress.com/2010/08/060_generatebusinessservice_thumb1.png?w=366&h=461)

http://guidoschmutz.wordpress.com/2010/08/08/oracle-service-bus-11g-and-db-adapter-a-different-more-integrated-approach/